# Page not found error when trying to access index controller in Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

In my codeigniter project, I am removing *index.php* extension from the URLs using htaccess file. But this is giving me

`404 (Page Not Found) Error`

when trying to access pages/functions in `Index` controller. I tried to load a page, http://site.org/projectname/index/language/french which gave me this error.

My htaccess code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projectname/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

You have to remove `/` before `index.php`